# Legacy code: window.parent.location.href="https:/home"

Tags: javascript, redirect, location-href, window.parent

I have inherited some code from our former developer and I found this piece of code.

```
<?php
   if($this->loginAction->isAuthenticated()){
?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      window.parent.location.href="https:/home";
   </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

I have been looking on it for a while and I have no idea why he put there the shortcut for the URL. I think that the URL should be https://mysite.com/home. I basically don't know what does this code do.

**Edit:** I know that this code is redirection if user is authenticated, but I don't know what the strange URL(https:/home) is doing there. This code is working.

Thank you for any help.

**Edit2:** According to my colleague, this is one of the JS secrets:) Going to test it. This two lines of code should have equal functionality:

```
window.parent.location.href="https:/home";
window.parent.location.href="https://www.my-testing.com/home";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the URI and it is valid according to the spec here: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt in section 3 as quoted here: ( the bold and highlights are mine)  This says that the scheme **https** followed by the separator colon **:** then the rest is optional. Thus the single forward slash is likely interpreted as the root or "full" URI of "https://home" or simply the "/home" of the current provider.  Likely this then looks like "https://www.example.com/home" if your site is www.example.com (it isn't but that one is in the specifications as a reserved name as well) which is the DNS address of your site.  Note that if the scheme were missing as "//www.ourbug.net" then that would be translated into the current scheme in use (http or https for most resources)

### Quote from the reference:

**3. URI Syntactic Components**

The URI syntax is dependent upon the scheme.  In general, absolute
   URI are written as follows:

```
  <scheme>:<scheme-specific-part>
```

An absolute URI contains the name of the scheme being used ()
   followed by a colon (":") and then a string (the ) whose interpretation depends on the scheme.

The URI syntax does not require that the scheme-specific-part have
   any general structure or set of semantics which is common among all
   URI.  However, a subset of URI do share a common syntax for
   representing hierarchical relationships within the namespace.  **This
   "generic URI" syntax consists of a sequence of four main components:**

```
  <scheme>://<authority><path>?<query>
```

**each of which, except , may be absent from a particular URI.**
   For example, some URI schemes do not allow an  component,
   and others do not use a  component.

```
  absoluteURI   = scheme ":" ( hier_part | opaque_part )
```

URI that are hierarchical in nature use the slash "/" character for
   separating hierarchical components.  For some file systems, a "/"
   character (used to denote the hierarchical structure of a URI) is the
   delimiter used to construct a file name hierarchy, and thus the URI
   path will look similar to a file pathname.  This does NOT imply that
   the resource is a file or that the URI maps to an actual filesystem
   pathname.

```
  hier_part     = ( net_path | abs_path ) [ "?" query ]

  net_path      = "//" authority [ abs_path ]

  abs_path      = "/"  path_segments"
```

Comment: Reading specs is so much fun :) Bring all your friends and soft drinks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears to say if the login action is authenticated then redirect the user to a new url.

Seems like a bug to me.  I don't believe https:/home is anything more than a typo.

Comment: Yeah I know that is redirecting if the user is authenticated and I thought that is typo also, but evidently is not, because I have found the exact same shortcut on more places.

Comment: Is it possible something else is redirecting the url?

Comment: There is whole SSO implementation and the redirection back from IDP is hitting the page where is this code...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
   window.parent.location="https://www.my-testing.com/home";
</script>
```