# How to include jquery-1.10.2.js and jQuery-2.1.4.min.js together

Tags: php, jquery

Hello I am including jQuery-2.1.4.min.js and jquery-1.10.2.js together but I am getting error:

> custom.js:375 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a
>   function

If i remove jQuery-2.1.4.min.js then i m getting error in one price ranger. So i can not remove any one JS.

So how to use both so that my price ranger and autocomplete functionality works ?

**Script:**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mydirectorypath/js/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

**By Above code I am getting error $(...).autocomplete is not a
 function**

Comment: use [jquery.noconflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) and see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331193/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page) SO post.

Comment: yes i did but same result

Comment: You shouldn't need both. That error is a result of order you include scripts that depend on jQuery. Use one version and make sure it precedes all dependent plugins and code

Comment: But if I remove one of them my some functionality stop working. Even i changed the order but no result.

Comment: It lookslike that either one of the plugins need a code update. You probably will have no success in having multiple jQuery versions working.

Comment: Really doesn't make sense. If you are supporting older browsers everything should work fine with the `1.10.2` version as long as it is included before anything that uses jQuery and no other version of jQuery is included after any plugins are registered. Be more specific about actual errors not just saying *"not working"*

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use two jQuery in the same page. Like below

```
<!-- load jQuery 2.1.4 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="mydirectorypath/js/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_2_1_4 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Now you can use **jQuery_2_1_4** than the **$**

```
<!-- load jQuery 1.10.2 -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_10_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Now you can use **jQuery_1_10_2** than the **$**

Comment: Yes you must have to do that. Because some functionality jQuery 2.1.4 is not working on the jQuery 1.10.2. So you must have to differentiate the functionality of both the jQuery.

Comment: May i remove one of them ?

Comment: Yes it's better option than the use noConflict()

Comment: but if i remove one of them my price ranger or autocomplete not working

Comment: Find the replacement function for that in a different version.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use jQuery and jQuery UI you will need three things in this sequence:

1. The jQuery UI CSS, along with any customization/theme
2. jQuery library; usually minimized for space
3. The jQuery UI code library, also minimized.

For simplicity, here is an example of all three, in a CDN:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

This is the normal sequence that they are included, usually in your `<head>` tag so that if it is used within (later) head inclusions, it works.

Given all that, here is the code and sequence that would work if I used the sample from the Autocomplete page here:  https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript","AppleScript","Asp","BASIC","C","C++","Clojure",
      "COBOL","ColdFusion","Erlang","Fortran","Groovy","Haskell","Java",
      "JavaScript","Lisp","Perl","PHP","Python","Ruby","Scala","Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#myinput" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Then, in the body my input tag:

```
<input id="myinput" type="text"/>
```

Unless you need to support older browsers, then you ONLY need the 2.X version (2.2.2 demonstrated here) If you DO need to support older browsers, you should only need the 1.X version. To show it working I created this: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/op7Lq06g/

**EDIT:**

What about that missing HTTPS in your question:  To match your site, you exclude that from the linked tags, and it automatically per the HTML specification puts that in to match the page source from your site.  Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

For a detailed explanation including a link to the specification for that see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36638189/125981

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Please clarify.  Note that jQuery UI Autocomplete will work with either version.  I can only assume that IS the autocomplete you refer to since you do not indicate otherwise.  Keep in mind that with your question we have to make assumptions since you do NOT include the code where you actually USE either of the things you refer to. Nor do you indicate the code segment where you include the jQuery UI which must come AFTER the jQuery inclusion.